# Should I use durabond compound (20 or 45 minutes) to patch drywall large holes?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

I have a few drywall holes that I need to repair, ranging in size from approximately 1 inch to 2 inches. I also intend to re-screw in the same locations.

**My question is:** Since Durabond compound becomes very hard after drying, should I use Durabond to patch the drywall holes and then re-screw in the same spots?

Comment: What was the cause of the holes?  If anchors pulling out, then you need to find studs to either use directly or to screw wood/plywood to give holding power.

Comment: Durabond is not very forgiving because, as OP said, it dries hard as a rock, and cannot be sanded.  That means you have to get the finished surface right the first time.

Comment: It works well as a backing for drying compound.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you’re planning to put a screw in the same location, you’d be much better off to open up the hole a bit and slip a strip of plywood in to serve as backer. Screw the ply top and bottom and put a fresh patch of drywall in with a couple of screws. Tape, skim, etc.

Mesh and setting compound (20, 45, etc) work well together, but not as the last coat as they are hard to sand. All purpose premixed (or even better, topping mud) should go on top of the mesh.

Assuming you don’t want to buy a 2x2 chunk of drywall for this, don’t hesitate to ask for a freebie at the big box store. They always seem to have busted sheets around.